# map over an array to find a value and return the object

Tags: javascript

So I have a series of dates as such:

```
const accumulatedDates = ['2023-08-22', '2023-08-23', '2023-08-24']
```

and I have an object which contains the following:

```
const orderDataByDate = {2023-08-23: 1321, 2023-08-24: 2}
```

What i am trying to achieve is to map over `accumulatedDates` to find the value from `orderDataByDate` to build up an array. If it can be found, then return it in an object form like so `{2023-08-23: 1321}`, and if it cant be found, then return the value as zero i.e. `{2022-08-23: 0}`

The end result should something like this:

```
const results = [
{2023-08-22: 0},
{2023-08-23: 1321},
{2023-08-24: 2}
]
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
const results = accumulatedDates.map(date =>
  Object.keys(orderDataByDate).filter(key =>
    key === date
      ? {
          date: orderDataByDate[key]
        }
      : {
          date: 0
        }
  )
)
```

but not getting the desired result. The result i get is:

```
[
 ['2023-08-23', '2023-08-24']
 ['2023-08-23', '2023-08-24']
 ['2023-08-23', '2023-08-24']
]
```

which is completely off target to what im trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? What did your attempt return? Is there an error?

Comment: @mykaf have updated question with what im getting

Comment: Your filter function isn't returning a true boolean; it's returning an object, which is truthy, thus returns all and maps everything. I would probably filter first, then map the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the entries and build an object.

```js
const
    accumulatedDates = ['2023-08-22', '2023-08-23', '2023-08-24'],
    orderDataByDate = { '2023-08-23': 1321, '2023-08-24': 2 },
    result = Object.fromEntries(accumulatedDates.map(d => [d, orderDataByDate[d] || 0]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to use the `{[varname]: value}` syntax to allow you to use a variable as the key. E.g:

```js
accumulatedDates.map(date => {
  return {[date]: orderDataByDate[date] || 0}
})
```

This should give you an array with objects a la

```js
const results = [
   {2023-08-22: 0},
   {2023-08-23: 1321},
   {2023-08-24: 2}
]
```